# Bootstrap table-striped not working in some browsers

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm dealing with a strange behavior with the table-striped property of Bootstrap. For some reason, such property isn't working in some browsers that I have tested.

I have tested the code presented below:

```
 <body>

    <div class="container">
       <table class="table table-striped">
         <thead>
                 <tr>
                     <th>Firstname</th>
                     <th>Lastname</th>
                     <th>Email</th>
                 </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody>
                 <tr>
                     <td>John</td>
                     <td>Doe</td>
                     <td>john@example.com</td>
                 </tr>
                 <tr>
                     <td>Mary</td>
                     <td>Moe</td>
                     <td>mary@example.com</td>
                 </tr>
                 <tr>
                     <td>July</td>
                     <td>Dooley</td>
                     <td>july@example.com</td>
                 </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Such code didn't work on Chrome 43.0.23571.81, 43.0.2357.132 or in Firefox 36.0. (the remaining bootstrap properties worked nicely)

I have tested such code in other versions of aforementioned browsers and it worked as expected.

Any possible reason for such behavior?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the issue?

Comment: you missing an opening html tag in your code above